# Descobrir números em sequencia que multiplicados é um resultado

Tags: java, portugol

Hoje ajudei meu primo a resolver um exercício de matemática.
O exercicio pedia dois números em sequência que quando multiplicados o resultado é 16512 (128 * 129).
Gostaria de saber um código que resolvesse isso com qualquer número.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matematicamente, essa situação só pode ocorrer para números positivos que não são quadrados perfeitos, e, para descobrir se o número em questão cai nessa situação, basta testar se a raiz quadrada arredondada para baixo multiplicado pela raiz quadrada arredondada para cima resultam no número em questão. Validar os outros números, seria apenas desperdício.

Seguindo essa linha de raciocínio, considere o código a seguir:

```
// dado "numero", retorna:
// 1) [a, b], onde "a * b == numero", e "a" e "b" são consecutivos
// 2) [], quando não existem números consecutivos que multiplicados resultam em "numero"
public static int[] obtemConsecutivos(int numero) {
    // previne erro na raizQuadrada com números negativos
    if (numero > 0) {
        long raiz = Math.sqrt(numero);
        int primeiroConsecutivo = Math.floor(raiz);
        int segundoConsecutivo = Math.ceil(raiz);
        // previne situação de quadrado perfeito, como 4, 9, 16, 25...
        // nesse caso, o primeiro consecutivo será igual ao segundo
        if (primeiroConsecutivo + 1 == segundoConsecutivo) {
            // testa se consecutivos batem com o numero desejado
            if (numero == primeiroConsecutivo * segundoConsecutivo) {
                return [primeiroConsecutivo, segundoConsecutivo];
            }
        }
    }
    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basta um `for` até a raiz quadrada do número procurado:

```
public class Multiplicador {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            int i = 16512;
            int j = encontraPrimeiroNumeroMultiplicador(i);
            System.out.println("Encontrou " + j + " e " + (j+1) + " como fatores seguidos de " + i);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.println(e);    
        }
    }
    
    public static int encontraPrimeiroNumeroMultiplicador(int numeroProcurado) throws Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<=Math.sqrt(numeroProcurado+1); i++) {
            
            if(i * (i+1) == numeroProcurado) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Nenhum numero multiplicador encontrado para " + numeroProcurado);
    }
}
```

Alguns exemplos de saídas:

> Encontrou 128 e 129 como fatores seguidos de 16512
>
> Nenhum numero multiplicador encontrado para 16513
>
> Encontrou 99 e 100 como fatores seguidos de 9900
>
> Encontrou 2 e 3 como fatores seguidos de 6
>
> Nenhum numero multiplicador encontrado para 78

Por que basta procurar até a raiz quadrada? Porque nenhum número multiplicado pelo seu sucessor será menor do que o número ao quadrado; ou seja, N * (N+1) será maior que N * N, para qualquer número natural positivo.